# How to flag for moving to blender.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, migration, flagging

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58184/blender-to-collada-to-assimp-rigid-non-skinned-animation

I wanted to flag this as off-topic for migration to another site but the only option is to move it to meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com.  I flagged it as "other" instead, but it seems like more options (at least the common ones) should be displayed in that list of sites to suggest migration to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators can move to any site.  If you'd like to make a suggestion for a moderator to move to that, just use the regular "flag for moderator attention" feature.

Comment: Still, it seems silly that I can't just mark which site to move to (for the moderator's convenience if anything else) but rather have to type in the suggested destination site or leave it up to the moderate to figure it out.

Comment: Blender.SE is *just* getting off the ground; it's much more useful if you send folks over to ask their own questions, since that gives them an opportunity to look around, read the docs if they want, etc... Just shipping questions over can create a lot of unpleasant effort for a younger site, especially in cases where the asker doesn't immediately follow to clarify if there are questions on the question. @Sean

Comment: Fair enough.  I still think going forward it'd be a nice feature, but maybe not critical.

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to move question from Stackoverflow here. GD is not in the list of on-topic sites when you select off-topic.